# Change the format of the date which is a column of a list

Tags: date, powershell, format

So I got this code:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='application'} |
    Select Id,ProviderName,Message,TimeCreated
```

And it gives me the following output:

```
   Id ProviderName                   Message                            TimeCreated
   -- ------------                   -------                            -----------
  327 ESENT                          svchost (664) The database engi... 28.07.2014 14:46:24
  326 ESENT                          svchost (664) The database engi... 28.07.2014 14:46:24
 8224 VSS                            The VSS service is shutting dow... 28.07.2014 14:40:23
  903 Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP The Software Protection service... 28.07.2014 14:39:40
16384 Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP Successfully scheduled Software... 28.07.2014 14:39:40
  ...
```

How can I change the format of the dates to the "[Full date and time (long date and long time) using universal time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx#ECAA)" like **Thursday, August 30, 2007 6:21:52 PM**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='application'} |
    Select Id,ProviderName,Message,@{Label = "TimeCreated"; Expression = {Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format U}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a couple ways to do it. Here is one example.

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='application'} | 
    Select-Object Id,ProviderName,Message,@{Name='TimeCreated';Expression={[String]::Format("{0:U}", $_.TimeCreated)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='application'} |
    Select-object Id, ProviderName, Message, @{Name='TimeCreated';Expression={$_.TimeCreated.tostring('F')}}
```

and here are the standard format strings you can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx